# Parse HTML table by column

Tags: java, jsoup, html-table

I'm trying to parse an HTML table by column, and I think I've got the general algorithm right. But the rowspans are causing me trouble.

[Here is an example table.](https://kalender.phl.be/kalenterit2/index.php?kt=lk&yks=&cluokka=2TING&av=131209131215131210&guest=IT/phl&lang=fla&print=arkipaivat)

This is the code I'm using:

```
Elements rows = document.select("table.asio_basic > tbody > tr"); // get all tablerows
Elements dataCells = new Elements(); //Object to save all cells with data

for (int i = 0; i < rows.get(0).children().size(); i++) //iterate through the columns.
{       
    for (int j = 0; j < rows.size(); j++) //iterate through the rows
    {
        Element cell = rows.get(j).child(i); //get the cell in row j, column i

        if (cell.hasAttr("rowspan"))
        {
            j += Integer.parseInt(cell.attr("rowspan")); // add rowspan to counter to skip nonexistent cells
            dataCells.add(cell);
        }
    }
}
```

So my issue is that the position of the cell in a row doesn't correspond with its column, after I've been through a column with rowspans.

Just getting all data from the cells is not an option, as I need the dates from the headers to save the data properly.

Comment: +1 I've been having issues with spanning as well, except the table I'm working with has both colspans AND row spans which is just terrible. My approach is similar to yours in that I try to keep track of the spanning, but in my case I've been keeping track of the row/colspans in something like a 2D array indexed by the row/col, as keeping it as a single number is not enough.

Comment: @MxyL Yes, I've been thinking about something like that as well, though I was hoping there would be something more elegant than that. If I do work something out, I'll be sure to post it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally managed to get something working. I added an array to keep track of my rowspans. With this offset, I can access the `td`s that - in the hierarchy - belong to the previous column.

This is my code. I changed it slightly to work for any table with `rowspans`.

```
Document document = document = Jsoup.connect(URL).get(); //get the HTML page
Elements rows = document.select("table > tbody > tr"); //select all rows
int[] offsets = new int[rows.size()];

for (int i = 0; i < rows.get(0).children().size(); i++) //unless colspans are used, this should return the number of columns
{
    for (int j = 0; j < rows.size(); // loops through the rows of each column
    {
        Element cell = rows.get(j).child(i + offsets[j]); //get an individual cell

        if (cell.hasAttr("rowspan")) //if that cell has a rowspan
        {
            int rowspan = Integer.parseInt(cell.attr("rowspan"));

            for (int k = 1; k < rowspan; k++)
            {
                offsets[j + k]--; //add offsets to rows that now have a cell "missing"
            }

            j += rowspan - 1; //add rowspan to index, to skip the "missing" cells
        }
    }
}
```